# MYSQL: select rows from the past month using DATETIME?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I'm trying to select rows from mysql based on the `DATETIME`.

The `DATETIME` is stored like so: `2016-04-01 09:17:23`

my mysql query in my php file is like this:

```
$resultneg1 = mysqli_query($db_conx, "SELECT count(*) FROM ratings WHERE user='".$email."' AND type='neg' AND date_added <= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)");
             $rowneg1 = mysqli_fetch_row($resultneg1);
             $op_countconeg1= $rowneg1[0];
             echo $op_countconeg1;
```

The result above is always `0` even though there is a row inside mysql with `type='0' and user='useremail@gmail.com'`!

Could someone please advise on this issue?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `date_added >=` instead of `date_added <=`?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos, yes it should. thank you very much. that did it.